# how to setstate of an array of objects by multiple inputs?

Tags: react-native

I want to add all my input data in sizes state by multiple input but i only got the last input vale like

this result comes

```
[{
    id      : 5, 
    key     : "maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER", 
    value   : "15",
    slug    : "maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER",
    name    : "maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER"
}]
```

this is expected result

```
[
  {
    id      : 5, 
    key     : "maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER", 
    value   : "15", 
    slug    : " maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER",
    name    :"maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER"
  },
  {
    id      : 5, 
    key     : "maketomeasure - SHIRT CHEST", 
    value   : "14", 
    slug    : " maketomeasure - SHIRT CHEST",
    name    :"maketomeasure - SHIRT CHEST"
  }
]
```

this is my state for form

```
this.state={
    sizes:[]
}
```

and this is my form in which multiple inputs

```
 <TextInput
      style={styles.textStyle}
      placeholder={"Shirt Shoulder"}
      onChangeText={value => this.onChangeValue('maketomeasure - SHIRT SHOULDER', value)}
      defaultValue={this.state.makeToMeasure.shirtShoulder}
        />
  {/* <Text>SHIRT CHEST</Text> */}
  <TextInput
    placeholder="Shirt Chest"
    style={styles.textStyle}
    defaultValue={this.state.makeToMeasure.shirtChest}
    onChangeText={value => this.onChangeValue('maketomeasure - SHIRT CHEST', value)}
  />
```

and here is my onchangeText method

```
onChangeValue = (key,value) => {
    var a =5;
    var b=a++ ;

    this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    sizes: {
                ...prevState.sizes,
                key: key,
                value:value,
                name:value,
                id:b,
                slug:key
            }  
    })
    );
};
```